# How to get list of file dependencies in monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using Monaco Editor in my Electron app. My application works with JS and TS files.

When I create a model and then load it into the editor, I get this error:
[image]

Also, autocomplete does not work.

I know that in order to solve this problem, I need to create models of the requested files. However, I don't know of a good way to list these files.

There are two bad options that I considered:

1. Create models for all project files.
2. Parse each file yourself to get a list of its dependencies.

Does the Monaco Editor provide a way to get the dependencies without going through the two options I mentioned.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I am looking into this as well. It should be one of the most common questions regarding Monaco but the (third party) documentation is shockingly thin.

Comment: I haven't found a good way yet. For now, I'm forced to use https://github.com/dependents/node-precinct.